Vim: move in the INSERT mode between lines using left/right arrow keys
In Vim while in the INSERT mode, I would like to be able to move between lines using the left and right arrow keys. For example, if the cursor is at the beginning of a line and I press the left arrow key, I would like the cursor to move to the last character of the previous line.
This is trivial to set up for the NORMAL mode (set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l in .vimrc), but how do I make it work also in the INSERT mode?
Similarly, it would be nice if also Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right (to move between words) worked the same way (e.g., Ctrl+Left would move the cursor from the beginning of the first word on a given line to the beginning of the last word on the previous line).
Thanks.

:help 'whichwrap' also affects insert mode so you have nothing to do, Vim already behaves the way you want.

Thank you! Adding ,[,] to whichwrap in .vimrc (–> set whichwrap+=<,>,[,],h,l) does the trick.

As mentioned in the comments, you can add [ and ] to 'whichwrap' to make the Left and Right keys work in Insert (and Replace) mode:
    Allow specified keys that move the cursor left/right to move to the
    previous/next line when the cursor is on the first/last character in
    the line.  Concatenate characters to allow this for these keys:
        char   key    mode  ~
         b    <BS>   Normal and Visual
         s    <Space>    Normal and Visual
         h    "h"    Normal and Visual (not recommended)
         l    "l"    Normal and Visual (not recommended)
         <    <Left>     Normal and Visual
         >    <Right>    Normal and Visual
         ~    "~"    Normal
         [    <Left>     Insert and Replace
         ]    <Right

These are not present by default.

Thanks. After @romainl pointed me in the right direction, I added the salient bit to my comment so that others do not need to look through the manual themselves.

@nvx btw, welcome to [vi.se]! We prefer to put answers in "Answers" so they can be voted on, accepted, etc. Comments are typically transient and have other purposes. (As a meta comment, reading the manual is a skill well worth honing: :help 'whichwrap' would have answered your question immediately.)
